# Ajax returned text read differently by Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am returning a json object that Firefox reads correctly but IE doesnt.

for example: `if( data.returnedText=="OptionA"){...`

this is true as it should be in Firefox, but IE doesnt match.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the contents of what you're trying to compare to a page (or alert box) in IE? That may give you a hint as to what's up.

Comment: yes, the alert box is what is expected.

Comment: Have you tried a typeof(data.returnedText) in both IE and Firefox?

Comment: I've encountered this before and I determined that it was caused by using the asp.net development webserver instead of IIS.  This information will only be helpful if you're using asp.net ;)

Comment: @ken using vs developer. it appears to append a " " at the end of the text for some reason.